# How can I reverse the direction of a tag synonym? ([HTL] vs [Sightly])

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Years ago, I created a tag synonym, thinking it was a bidirectional relationship.

The synonym was for [htl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htl) and [sightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sightly)

Now I noticed, by inspecting the [synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms), that the relationship implies automatic retagging from one tag to another ([htl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htl) -> [sightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sightly)). Unfortunately, the relationship is the opposite of what makes sense for these two tags.

Sightly was renamed to HTL by Adobe and it would make sense for questions tagged with [sightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sightly) to change to [htl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htl), but the way the synonym is currently set up it is mapping the other way round.

How can I reverse the relationship?

Comment: A moderator is necessary to make this change. So I guess the answer is "make a meta post" and wait for a mod to action the request?

Comment: The way this question is currently phrased there are two separate questions. The explicit: "How to reverse the tag mapping" which would be [meta-tag:tag-synonyms] (asking about who has the privileges to do this action) but there is also the implicit request to reverse the mapping which is a [meta-tag:synonym-request]. I've included both tags for this reason.

Comment: I thought so @HenryEcker, thanks for your response. Does this post count or do I need to create a new one? :D

Comment: What I would recommend is editing this into a *request* to make the change, including a detailed explanation/justification. Remove the part asking "how".

Comment: Even if it matches the current name HTL does not seem like a good tag either, since three letter acronyms can match many things. According to wikipedia, a somewhat on-topic meaning would be "human language technology" and your intended meaning does not even show up. How about htl-adobe or similar?

Comment: Considering the full name is "HTML Template Language", that might be a good name, @MisterMiyagi: [[tag:html-template-language]]. [[tag:htl]] could be a synonym. Otherwise, I'd vote for [[tag:adobe-htl]], because I think you have the vendor and product name backwards in your suggestion. But it seems Adobe didn't intend for this to be Adobe-specific (they donated it to Apache something-or-other), so it seems inappropriate to put their company/brand name in there.

Comment: I don't represent Adobe, I suppose it would be prudent to take the question to them. Let me see if I can find a person to contact. @bertrand-delacretaz maybe you could find out if Adobe have a preference?

Comment: Note that @ mentions only work for users who have participated in the post on which the comment is attached, (and moderators I think?) so Bertrand's not going to get notified about this meta post just with that. You'd have to hunt down a post of theirs and ask them to look at this meta post.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah, I've noticed. I've asked through other channels too.